# Heroku Deployment Error: R10 (Boot timeout) - Web process failed to bind to $PORT

Tags: python, heroku, streamlit, bitbucket-pipelines

**Problem:**

I am facing an issue during the deployment of my ChainLit Python application on Heroku. The application fails to start, and I am encountering the following error logs:

**Latest Error Logs on Heroku:**

```
2023-12-14T18:41:28.421590+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `chainlit run genai.py`
2023-12-14T18:41:31.896224+00:00 app[web.1]: 2023-12-14 18:41:31 - Your app is available at http://localhost:8000
2023-12-14T18:42:28.988398+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2023-12-14T18:42:29.001471+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2023-12-14T18:42:29.152337+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2023-12-14T18:42:29.180288+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

**Description:**

The application fails to start on Heroku, and the error `Error R10 (Boot timeout)` is reported. This error indicates that the web process failed to bind to the `$PORT` within 60 seconds of launch, resulting in the process being terminated with a SIGKILL signal.

**Bitbucket Pipelines Configuration:**

```yaml
image: python:3.12-bullseye

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          name: Build
          script:
            - echo "Building the app"
            - pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip
            - pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
            - export AZURE_OPENAI_KEY=$AZURE_OPENAI_KEY
            - export AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT=https://$AZURE_OAI_RESOURCE_NAME.azure.com/
            - export AZURE_OPENAI_VERSION=2023-09-15-preview
            - export AZURE_OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT=$AZURE_OAI_DEPLOYMENT
            - export AZURE_OPENAI_MODEL=gpt-3.5-turbo
            - git archive --format=tar.gz master -o my-app.tar.gz
          artifacts:
            - my-app.tar.gz

      - step:
          name: Deploy to production
          deployment: production
          caches:
            - pip
          script:
            - pipe: atlassian/heroku-deploy:2.3.0
              variables:
                HEROKU_API_KEY: $HEROKU_API_KEY
                HEROKU_APP_NAME: $HEROKU_APP_NAME
                ZIP_FILE: my-app.tar.gz
```

**Procfile:**

```
web: chainlit run genai.py
```

**requirements.txt:**

```
python-dotenv
langchain
openai
termcolor
chainlit
gunicorn
```